Why can't the question of whether Illyrian was centum or satem be resolved by a simple letter-frequency analysis of the attested Illyrian toponyms?
There have been many papers published about whether Illyrian was centum or satem, or at least touching that topic. Including my paper "Etimologija Karašica", published in Valpovački Godišnjak in 2022, where I search for patterns in the Croatian toponyms that can be easily explained if you assume Illyrian is centum and calculate their p-values using basic information theory (Collision Entropy and Birthday Paradox).
But now I am thinking: Why does one even need to go that far? Can't the problem of whether Illyrian was centum or satem be simply solved by a letter-frequency analysis of the attested Illyrian toponyms?
Think of it this way: *k was a relatively rare phoneme in the Proto-Indo-European language (not exceedingly rare like *a or *b, but still rare). *kj was much more common. So if, in the attested Illyrian toponyms, /k/ is more common than /s/ (and it seems to me that it is, though I haven't counted that), that strongly suggests Illyrian was a centum language, right?
Now, if /s/ is more common than /k/, then it's a bit complicated because we don't know how common *s was in Proto-Indo-European (for many Indo-European roots, we don't know whether they started with *s or whether it's a contamination, that's called s-mobile). Still, there seems to be a relatively simple solution: don't count the toponyms that start with s+consonant (such as Stulpi, Stridon, or Scardona), as that is where s-mobile occurs.
Has anybody tried to determine whether Illyrian was centum or satem that way? What were the results?

If you can't reconstruct a preform you can't say whether a given toponym even is Illyrian as opposed to some substrate; if you can reconstruct a preform you don't need any of this. Note that it's not the case that a language has to be either centum or satem, and also that merely whether or not a language assibilated original palatovelars is not diagnostic: French is centum but has a sibilant in its reflex of *k̑m̥tom, Luwian assibilated the palatovelars but is neither centum nor satem.

the frequency of PIE *k is irrelevant. Even if we could reliably identify Illyrian toponyms (we can't), and if the PIE antecedents of the Illyrian toponomasticon have the same phoneme distribution as PIE roots in general (seems unlikely, but is certainly unproven), then the frequency of /k/ in Illyrian would be dominated by the frequency of *ḱ in a centum language, and the frequency of *kʷ in a satem one. Note also that *kʲ is a very poor choice of notation for *ḱ as it reifies its supposed "palatal" nature, when there is, at best, little reason to believe it was actually palatal in PIE itself

@Tristan Isn't *kw even more rare than *k?

*kʷ, not *kw. *kʷ is plentiful. Not quite as plentiful as *ḱ, but still very common. *kw is indeed extremely rare (with the exception of some outcomes of the boukolos rule, but that should probably be analysed as phonemically still */kʷw/). In centum languages *kʷ & *kw should probably be treated identically (with some possible exceptions, depending on what's going on in Greek hippos for instance, although that's ofc a *ḱw > centum *kw not an original *kw), but in satem languages the former gives k, whilst the latter gives kw (typically > kv in the actual attested satem languages)

@Tristan "*kʷ is plentiful. Not quite as plentiful as *ḱ, but still very common.". Do you have some reference for that? If that's true, then, fine, I was very mistaken about the distribution of phonemens within PIE.

@Tristan Are you sure about those frequencies? LIV² (which of course includes only verbal roots, but should still be reasonably representative) has 139 roots starting with any of the unvoiced velars; of these, 13 are indeterminably *k or *k̑, and 22 are indeterminably *k or kʷ. Excluding those, the numbers are: *kʷ 15; *k̑ 42; *k 47. Including them in all potential categories, the numbers are: *kʷ 37; *k̑ 55; *k 82. In either case, *k is the commonest and *kʷ the rarest. (There are five roots in *ku̯- and five in *k̑u̯-.)

@JanusBahsJacquet huh, that surprises me. The relative rarity of *k is frequently discussed (especially by those arguing that there are only two dorsal series, but also by those arguing that *ḱ is not in fact palatal).

@Tristan To be honest, I was surprised as well – I was going to say the same thing in reply to FA’s comment and went looking for numbers to back it up, and then the numbers didn’t fit at all. Unless my memory is playing tricks on me, though, I do believe I’ve heard it argued that *k is suspiciously rare specifically at the end of roots, rather than in onset position – but I don’t have any properly structured data to analyse to verify or refute whether that holds true.

@Tristan Get used to those things. A lot of historical linguistics are well-known things that fall apart when scrutinized with hard data. Like in Croatian toponyms: It is commonly stated that *ser was the Illyrian word for "to flow", and you would expect, based on that, that river names starting with s-r are common. But, in reality, river names starting on k-r are a lot more common.

@JanusBahsJacquet that would seem plausible. Accepting the idea that at least some instances of *k are actually *ḱ but where "depalatlised" reflexes in certain root shapes (e.g. before resonants) have been generalised by analogy we'd expect them mostly at the start of roots where certain ablaut grades would put them in such environments. From my very cursory look over LIV2 yesterday it did seem that the *k roots were disproportionately of the shape *keR(C) (where such analogy could reasonably have taken place) but I didn't do any actual numerical comparison, so take it with a grain of salt

The problem is, you need to make a few big assumptions to do this sort of analysis:

All of these toponyms, and only these toponyms, are Illyrian
These toponyms are drawn randomly from the Illyrian vocabulary
Illyrian had no sound changes affecting velars at the beginning of a word (e.g. Grimm's Law)

And none of these assumptions are necessarily valid.
For the first one, we would need to know substantially more than we do about Illyrian to be sure which toponyms are Illyrian and which aren't.
For the second, toponyms are generally not made up of random words; certain types of words are vastly overrepresented in them (e.g. /h/ within a word is very rare in English but fairly common in English town names because of the -ham suffix).
For the third, compare Luwian, which merged *k, *g, and *gh at the start of a word, giving many more words starting with /k/ than with /z/, but the latter is the regular outcome of *ḱ. (Luwian is not generally considered a satem language because it preserves labiovelars and lacks the ruki law, but it did assibilate the "palatovelars".)
